# How long Celery stores results, can I limit this time

Tags: celery

I want to use Сelere with Redis as backend, I'll have a process that create tasks, stores ids and then runs again and checks statuses.
How to clear results and statuses that I don't need anymore, could I restrict time Сelery stores result ?
Like this:

```
task_id = task.apply_async().id
store_id(task_id) # my code, doesn't relate to celery
```

Then I will get tasks and check statuses:

```
task_id = get_id() # my code, doesn't relate to celery
task = AsyncResult(task_id)
# do something with task
# now I don't need Celery to store this result
```

Answer (score 6):

Celery save the result for a day by default.

You can however adjust this value with `result_expires`.

Here are the [docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/configuration.html#std-setting-result_expires).

> Default: Expire after 1 day.
>
> Time (in seconds, or a timedelta object)
> for when after stored task tombstones will be deleted.

Comment: @user2674414 did it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can mention this in your settings.py:

```
CELERY_RESULT_EXPIRES = 3600
```

I limit the expire time to 1 hour (60 * 60 = 3,600). The default value for this is one day (86,400 seconds).